# on/in/with- which of these go best with the given idiom?

Tags: prepositions, grammaticality

From being great at sports to knocking it right out the park **with** your academics, you've done really well.

From being great at sports to knocking it right out the park **on** your academics, you've done really well.

From being great at sports to knocking it right out the park **in** your academics, you've done really well.

What's the difference in the meaning between these sentences, with respect to the preposition used? Or do they bear the same meaning? Are all the sentences grammatically correct?

Comment: but, in other cases, like if someone got did a good job of something, you could complement them saying "you knocked it out of the park ON that one", here we're using on, right? Or would you suggest we use **with** here as well? @Lambie

Comment: It would still be with: You knocked it out of the park with that one. with that hit or shot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How do you "knock something out of the park"? In baseball, you do it with a baseball bat.

How do you do anything in sports when a sport involves an object? (tennis racket, baseball bat, cricket bat, football, etc.), You do your thing "with those objects" Right? And I am sure it is the same idea in your language.

So, if it is used metaphorically, ***with a bat*** can be replaced by just about anything as in:

- with your grades (academics)
- with your presentation
- with your comments

etc.

Comment: @FumbleFingers The academics is just for the sake of the OP. In AmE, academics could mean your grades i.e. marks in BrE for courses.

Comment: oic. I was half-inclined to understand it as equivalent to ***academia***, in which case it would probably take the ***in*** preposition, as with *He knocks it outta the park / does really well **in class / in academia***.

Comment: @FumbleFingers academics versus sports, for example. Suffolk University academics span more than 100 undergraduate, graduate, and professional programs of study. https://www.suffolk.edu/academics

Comment: Sounds a bit like the way I might use *[the] **humanities***, for example (collectively, all those "academic" subject areas that don't count as "sciences"). And I can certainly get my head around *He's crap at hard science, but he knocks it outta the park **in the humanities*** (or ***...with the humanities*** - both versions work for me there).

Comment: @FumbleFingers academics versus athletics "My first year, I didn't play lacrosse. I just focused on my academics, and I struggled a lot." In her second year, https://www.independent.co.uk/student/student-life/being-a-high-level-athlete-at-oxbridge-the-good-the-bad-and-the-advice-8951368.html The Independent is a British publication. Enough, OK?